# Is it possible to POST from the same URL without refreshing the page?

Tags: node.js, ajax, express, post, feathersjs

I'm using ajax to do so and am responding with `res.end` on the backend but so far, I can only POST once. Here is my code:

## Server

```
app.post("/awesome", passwordless.restricted({ failureRedirect: "/" }), (req, res, next) => {
  // ...do a bunch of stuff
  res.end();
});
```

## Client

```
$("[data-new-save]").on("click", function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/awesome",
    type: "POST",
    data: awesomeDetails,
    success: function () {
      console.log("Cool beans");
      refreshContent(); // Re-renders content

      // Feedback
      $("nav").after("<div class=\"flash success\">Success!</div>");

      setTimeout(function () {
        $(".flash").remove();
      }, 5000);
    },
    error: function () {
      console.log("Welp");

      // Feedback
      $(".navigation").after("<div class=\"flash error\">Failure</div>");

      setTimeout(function () {
        $(".flash").remove();
      }, 5000);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Are you saying that the button no longer functions after your initial POST? Or that the server doesn't handle the second request?

Comment: Hmm! The button doesn't respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a case for event-delegation. The best guess I have is that your `refreshContent()` function is removing the original `[data-new-save]` elements and creating new ones. This will cause the bound `click` event to be removed as well as it is a property of the DOM nodes that existed when it was originally called. You can get around this by delegating the event to a DOM node that does not get "refreshed", I'm assuming that the `<body>` tag does not get redrawn, only some set of children, so if you target `<body>` and look for selectors that match `"[data-new-save]"` it should function properly:

```
$('body').on('click', "[data-new-save]", function () {
   $.ajax({
    url: "/awesome",
    type: "POST",
    data: awesomeDetails,
    success: function () {
      console.log("Cool beans");
      refreshContent(); // Re-renders content

      // Feedback
      $("nav").after("<div class=\"flash success\">Success!</div>");

      setTimeout(function () {
        $(".flash").remove();
      }, 5000);
    },
    error: function () {
      console.log("Welp");

      // Feedback
      $(".navigation").after("<div class=\"flash error\">Failure</div>");

      setTimeout(function () {
        $(".flash").remove();
      }, 5000);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: That was it, thanks! Just when you thought you had `event-delegation` figured out.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i used for something similar:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myform').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url : $(this).attr('action') ||     window.location.pathname,
            type: "GET",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                $("#form_output").html(data);
            },
            error: function (jXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
});
```